# Django rest framework image upload error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is my UserProfile model,

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    badge = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/badges/', null=True)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/user/', blank=True, null=True)
```

And this is the Serializer class,

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('badge', 'reputation', 'status', 'thumbnail',)
```

My API to update an image looks like this,

```
class CreateUpdateUserThumbnail(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('user_id'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"Error": "User does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        request.data['user_id'] = user.id
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the error that I get when I try to upload an image using POSTMAN.

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: bouncer_userprofile.user_id
```

How do I associate a user_id with the serializer data?

Comment: what about the answers is one help you?

Comment: @BearBrown I'm still having some issues, could you please take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554265/django-rest-framework-errors-in-trying-to-persist-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `user_profile` instance on `UserProfileSerializer` instantiation

```
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(instance=user.profile, data=request.data)
```

Your view will look like this

```
class CreateUpdateUserThumbnail(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('user_id'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"Error": "User does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(instance=user.profile, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

the [request.data](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) is [immutable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) so you should to create the copy first:

```
data = request.data.copy()
data['user_id'] = user.id
serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=data)
```